# Is Mangirl based off a real story to some degree?

Tags: mangirl

Mangirl is about a group of girls who start up their own manga magazine called Earth Star Entertainment.

While I was looking up some info about the show, I noticed that the original manga was serialized in "Earth Star Entertainment's *Comic Earth Star* magazine" (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangirl!#Manga)). This seems to be a real company with [a real website](http://earthstar.jp/) that even shares its logo with the fictional company's logo in the show.

[image: Screenshot from Mangirl anime showing a character's badge with the fictional company name and logo]

Is any of Mangirl based on anything from the real life Earth Star Entertainment? For example, were the creators of the real life company all females or all amateurs, similar to the characters in the show?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty difficult to find information about Earth Star Entertainment, but from what I can tell, I don't see any similarities. According to its [website](http://earthstar.jp/company.php), it was established in 2006 and its current director is Masashi Kikuta and the president is K. Makuuchi. Masashi is a man's name, so presumably, Masashi Kikuta is a man. The major affiliated talent for the anime is a woman, but there doesn't seem to be any specific link to anything that you mentioned.